# Is `sizeof` allowed inside `#if` conditions?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

According to [CPPReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional), `#if` is followed by a constant expression. `sizeof` is a valid operator in constant expressions. But when I write this and compile it with clang or gcc, it fails:

```c
#if sizeof(char) == 1
#endif
```

clang’s output:

```
sizeof in preprocessor directive.c:1:5: error: function-like macro 'sizeof' is not defined
#if sizeof(char) == 1
    ^
1 error generated.
```

gcc’s output:

```
sizeof in preprocessor directive.c:1:11: error: missing binary operator before token "("
    1 | #if sizeof(char) == 1
      |           ^
```

Is CPPReference wrong or are the compilers wrong?

Comment: Logically, the preprocessor runs before the compiler has any idea what size types have. As far as the wording in the standard, it sounds like they define constants as being literals basically. Sizeof is a compile-time constant, but it doesn't seem to fall under the definition of "constants" in your link.

Comment: Also, the output of `sizeof` isn't constant. For example, `sizeof(a)` given `int a[n];` results `n * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: You need to read the whole sentence:
"The expression is a constant expression, using only constants and identifiers, **defined using #define directive.**". `sizeof` isn't a #defined constant.

Comment: Yes, this does not mention operators. Operators are allowed and are neither constants nor identifiers and are not defined using #define. They are allowed. `sizeof` seems an operator to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are both correct and it seems you have misunderstood what cppreference says.

From the standard draft (N3096) 6.10.1, Conditional inclusion:

> Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the defined unary operator), just as in normal text. If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the defined unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined. After all replacements due to macro expansion and evaluations of `defined` macro expressions, `has_include` expressions, `has_embed` expressions, and `has_c_attribute` expressions have been performed, **all remaining identifiers other than true (including those lexically identical to keywords such as false) are replaced with the pp-number 0, true is replaced with pp-number 1**, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens compose the controlling constant expression which is evaluated according to the rules of 6.6.

(emphasis mine)

That means from the perspective of the preprocessor, in the context of `#if`, `sizeof(char)==1` is simply replaced to produce `0(0)==1`, since that is not a valid constant expression, the program is ill-formed and the compiler should issue a diagnostic, which the compilers actually do and are hence conforming.

`sizeof` is not special at all here, nor is `char`. They are just like any other identifiers that have not been `#defined`, and is replaced with 0. You can test by yourself by things like `#if sizeof *1`, `#if char+1` and more.

The cppreference quote is not wrong. From your link, the full sentence is

> The expression is a constant expression, using only constants and identifiers, defined using #define directive. Any identifier, which is not literal, non defined using #define directive, evaluates to ​0.

This basically states the same thing as in the standard, and it certainly does not mean "any constant expression can be used here" as you seem to believe.

I think the above should already be enough to answer your question. Just to make it more clear that the codes cannot possibly work as you expect them to, as the comments point out, the handling of `sizeof` happens in phase 7 of translation, long after the last phase of preprocessing, phase 4. Informally, I would just say that `sizeof` is handled by the compiler and the preprocessor knows nothing about it. Whichever way you put it, it is impossible for `sizeof(char)==1` to evaluate to true in a `#if` condition.

Comment: It was unclear to me that “identifier” includes keywords. I generally use “identifier” to exclude keywords (when talking about programming languages in general).
Additionally, I find that saying the identifier evaluates to something is unclear, since in normal expressions `sizeof` would not be evaluated. It would be clearer to say “replace”.

Comment: In addition, the CPPReference article omits operators from the list of things allowed. From this, I assumed that all operators are allowed, and I considered `sizeof` to be an operator.

Comment: I guess then it is fair to say that cppreference is not clear enough, but I still won't go so far to say it's wrong. When dealing with preprocessor tokens, the words "identifier" and "operator" need to be interpreted with that context taken into consideration. For example, `_Pragma` is an operator in this context according to N3096.

Answer (score 0):

The CPPReference is missing the precision that keywords which have the form of identifiers are handled as identifiers and not keywords for the purpose of the evaluation of the constant expression. That precision was already present in C89.